# how to fix if .media$thumbnail.url not found?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm Building a widget for blogger

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mycallback(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
        if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
          var postUrl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
          break;
        }
      }
      var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
      var postSummary = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;
      var Thumb = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
      var item = '<div class="wrapper"><img src='+ Thumb +' /><h3><a href=' + postUrl + '>' + postTitle + '</h3></a><p>' + postSummary + '</p></div>';
      document.write(item);
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://smag-soratemplates.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=5&alt=json-in-script&callback=mycallback"></script>
```

but if there is no image in the post or cant find `.media$thumbnail.url`
the widget stops working , anyone know how to fix that ? or to show an alternative image?
sorry i'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all i found the solution
by replacing this code

```
var Thumb = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
```

with this code

```
 if (json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail)      
{       
Thumb = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;            
}
else      
{       
Thumb= "'Image url'";       
}
```

Comment: Can you please upvote / choose the answer that was most appropriate (if any). Thanks.

Comment: Also, you should probably use if(json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail && json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url). See my answer for more info on how you can make the code a bit cleaner / more robust. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's failing when the thumbnail does not exist, then you can put a check for the thumbnail

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mycallback(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
        if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
          var postUrl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
          break;
        }
      }
      var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
      var postSummary = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;
      var Thumb = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;

      if( typeof Thumb == "undefined" ) {
           Thumb = '/Your custom image url';
      }

      var item = '<div class="wrapper"><img src='+ Thumb +' /><h3><a href=' + postUrl + '>' + postTitle + '</h3></a><p>' + postSummary + '</p></div>';
      document.write(item);
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://smag-soratemplates.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=5&alt=json-in-script&callback=mycallback"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use or(||) in the Thumb definition like that

```
var Thumb = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url || 'https://i.imgur.com/5WMAvAu.gif';
```

Here, if `json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url` is undefine/false/null, Thumb is set to 'https://i.imgur.com/5WMAvAu.gif' as your default image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that all of the values are present:

```
json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url
```

as any of these items could be null / undefined:

```
json
json.feed
json.feed.entry[i]
json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail
json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url
```

At the least, you should check:

```
if(json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail && json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url)
```

Also, it's probably worth rewriting this code as follows:

```
let entry = json.feed.entry[i];
```

to save yourself some typing (and to stop all the object look ups each time when using dots to reference nested objects).

The code then becomes:

```
let url = '';
if (entry.media$thumbnail && media$thumbnail.url) {
    url = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
}
else {
    url = 'the default image URL';
}
```